# Hit one key to hold a second key down, until third is pressed

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to get the following behavior with AutoHotKey: When the `A` key is pressed, AHK holds down the `S` key until the `D` key is pressed. The following script isn't working as expected:

```
a::
    Send {s Down}
    return

d::
    if (GetKeyState("s", "P"))
        {
        Send {s Up}
        }
    return
```

Neither is the following:

```
a::
    release_s = 0
    Loop
        {
        SendInput, s
        if release_s
            break
        }
    return

d::
    release_s = 1
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
a::Send, {s down}

d::
    if(GetKeyState("s")) {
        Send, {s up}
    }
return
```

Problem in your code:

`GetKeyState("s", "P")` will only account for **physical** keys. <kbd>S</kbd> on the other has has been sent as a **virtual** key by AHK.

Answer (score 0):

Sending {s Down} will not cause repetition of a key.  You need to use a loop. Give this a try:

```
a::
    stop = 0
    Loop 
    {
        SendInput, s
        Sleep 50 ;adjust for speed of repetition
        if stop
            break
    }
    return


d::
    stop = 1
    return
```

Comment: Repetition? What repetition? If I hold down a key on my keyboard, I'm holding it down, not repeating anything. The moment I press it my keyboard tells the computer "key X is down" and the moment I depress it my keyboard says "key X is up". Am I missing something?

Comment: Directly from the documentation: When a key is held down via the method above, it does not begin auto-repeating like it would if you were physically holding it down (this is because auto-repeat is a driver/hardware feature). However, a Loop can be used to simulate auto-repeat.  http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Comment: But I _don't want_ auto-repeat. I just want the key to be held down. Think about a video game, for example: holding 'left' makes the player character move left for as long as you're holding it. There's no auto-repeat happening; the key is either down or it's up.

Comment: You can achieve this by removing the `Sleep 50` line. There is now no delay between the sendinputs and therefore simulates being held down. If this does not work for you, I'm out of ideas. Best of luck.

Comment: Nope, no avail. The keys do nothing and then AHK complains about too many hotkeys.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#games) entry in FAQ, that should help you out.

Comment: A different script worked before, so the app ignoring keys is not an issue.